# CleanUp Time not working for DIFF Backups

Tags: sql-server, backup, ola-hallengren

We have a database server where the test database is "refreshed" with the backup of prod database every day at 22:00.

- The first backup after the restore is a differential backup, because we are using the `ChangeBackupType = Y` switch.
- Our `CleanupTime` parameter is set to 48 hours, which works fine for Full and TLog backups.
- However the `CleanupTime` parameter does not work for the Diff backups that are created because of the `ChangeBackupType` being set to `Y`.

Any ideas where the problem lies? We do not explicitly use the Diff backups job, so there is no `CleanupTime` I can set.

Definition Full Backup
`sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d aspMaintenance -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'ALL_DATABASES', @BackupType = 'FULL', @NumberOfFiles = 1, @Verify = 'N', @CleanupTime = 42, @CheckSum = 'Y', @DirectoryStructure = '{DatabaseName}{DirectorySeparator}{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b`

Definition Log Backup
`sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d aspMaintenance -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup] @Databases = 'ALL_DATABASES', @ChangeBackupType = 'Y', @BackupType = 'LOG', @Verify = 'N', @CleanupTime = 48, @CheckSum = 'Y', @DirectoryStructure = '{DatabaseName}{DirectorySeparator}{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b`

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possibly [edit] your question and provide the job step details of your two (or three) backups jobs? I have an idea, but would like to see your SQL Server Agent Job details for the OLA backup jobs first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution, which you are using to perform your backup jobs, currently does no cleanup when when @ChangeBackupType = 'Y' and the backup type is changed.

I could find no official documentation of that, but the current version of the DatabaseBackup.sql script has checks that skips cleanup completely in this case, as can be seen in these two permalinks to the relevant lines of code in the official repository:

- https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/blob/3fb051dd500c4656190eb2959cf28270b7e47fc1/DatabaseBackup.sql#L3414C43
- https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/blob/3fb051dd500c4656190eb2959cf28270b7e47fc1/DatabaseBackup.sql#L3907

There are open issues in the official repository for enhancing cleanup, such as the two ones linked below, but there has been no progress on them for a long time.

- https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/179
- https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/166

Comment: Thanks, Marcelo. 

It is only one database and the restore time is always 22.00. 

I will create a job running the DIFF backup for this database at 22.10. Backup type has not to be changed and cleanup should work.